# cannot enter caret "^" in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I cannot enter the caret symbol "^" in bash (5.0.16), I have tried it in st and urxvt.
It works in any other program (browser, dmenu) and shell (sh, python) so I don't think it's a hotkey problem ( I use sxhkd). xev registers the key as well.
I can provide the files that are sourced by bash on startup but this problem appeared without making any changes to these files.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Which keys are you pressing to insert this character? And which keyboard layout do you have? Also, what do you mean it works in `sh`/`python`? Which terminal are those running in?

Comment: I am pressing shift and 6, standard us layout. What I mean is that when I open a terminal, my default shell is bash. If I then enter python, I enter the python command prompt, in which shift + 6 works correctly to enter ^. This works in st and urxvt